# General constructor value

Tags: c++

I just got into c++ since last week and as I'm trying to create a little rpg game, I got stuck in a point where I'd rather abandon the idea of OOP and make many integers and write values for each class.

I tried some ideas that I thought were great, but only errors were to be expected.

The main point is that I made a constructor of a class with the int attack, defense and so on, but to call it, i have to specify the class (eg. `wizard.getAttack()`).

I have 1 class and 5 instances of it. When the time comes to attack the enemy, i don't have a solution to input a general attack value of the object that has been chosen (such as `battle = attackPlayer - defenseEnemy;` or something like that).

It looks like this:

```
class Player
{
private:
    int attack;
    int defense;
    int evasion;
    string name;
public:
    Player(int atk = 0, int def = 0, int ev = 0, string nameClass = "Wiz") {
        attack = atk;
        defense = def;
        evasion = ev;
        name = nameClass;
    }

    int getAttack() { return attack; }

    int getDefense() { return defense; }

    int getEvasion() { return evasion; }

    string getName() { return name; }
};

int choice;
//int battle;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hi what class do you choose?" << endl;
    cin >> choice;

    Player wizard(60, 40, 60, "wizard");
    Player warrior(50, 60, 40, "warrior");
    Player paladin(40, 70, 50, "paladin");
    Player druid(60, 40, 60, "druid");
    Player assassin(70, 30, 70, "assassin");

    switch (choice)
    {
    case 1:
        wizard.getAttack(), wizard.getDefense(), wizard.getEvasion(), wizard.getName();
        break;
    case 2:
        warrior.getAttack(), warrior.getDefense(), warrior.getEvasion(), warrior.getName();
        break;
    }

    // battle = attackPlayer - attackEnemy;

    Player treant (60, 40, 60, "treant");

    cout << "Hello " << choice << endl;
};
```

I think it's easier with a many integers that could work for each class and each enemy, but if i would have to review the values it would take a lot of time. And as c++ have oop tools, I thought I could use them.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: I'm using visual studio and the version is on default, so i suppose it is trying to work with both c++14 and c++17 or latest versions

Comment: Instead of calling one of the 5 classes.getAttack() to attack the enemy, i want a to make a general variable that can choose by default the chosen class, so i dont make wizard.getAttack against enemy.getDefense(), more like it attackPlayer - defenseEnemy.

Comment: Alright, I followed your advice and changed it to c++ 17.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you are asking. You have one class but multiple default instantiation values for it. You could make one base class and have different derived classes with unique attack functions for each - via an overridden `attackOpponent()` function. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/Bt7pfi)

Comment: Your terminology is off. For example: You have one *class*, `Player`. You have six *objects* of that class: `wizard`, `warrior`, `paladin`, `druid`, `assassin`, and `treant`. This can be confusing for readers, especially since you have not clearly described your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are all sorts of issues with your design, and the decision to have the user enter an opaque number. But - I'll try to address what I *think* you're asking. It seems like what you want to have is:

```
Player player_templates[] = {
   {60, 40, 60, "wizard"},
   {50, 60, 40, "warrior"},
   {40, 70, 50, "paladin"},
   {60, 40, 60, "druid"},
   {70, 30, 70, "assassin"},
};
```

and now, if you get a `choice` number, you can just use `player_templates[choice]` and get the values you need, without repeating yourself several times. Another option could be using:

```
std::vector<Player> player_templates = {
   {60, 40, 60, "wizard"},
   {50, 60, 40, "warrior"},
   {40, 70, 50, "paladin"},
   {60, 40, 60, "druid"},
   {70, 30, 70, "assassin"},
};
```

in which case you could get the number of templates using `player_templates.size()` without spelling it out. There are other pros and cons to using an `std::vector` rather than an array.

Answer (score 1):

There are few points in your question will be important to highlight:

1. > I have 5 classes

   You mixed up terms *class* and *object*. `Player` - is a class.
   `Druid` is an *instance* of a *class* (or *object*). The question
   was fixed, but this  [article](https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_classes.asp)  may be useful for understanding
   the difference.
2. > I'd rather abandon the idea of OOP and make many integers and write
   >   values for each class.

   *OOP* has [several ideas](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mkagrahari/introduction-to-object-oriented-programming-concepts-in-C-Sharp/) (and [here](https://www.quora.com/What-do-the-4-principles-of-OOP-mean) )  which one do you think
   you abandon? I think you abandon nothing. Keeping *int* value inside a
   *class* - is called [encapsulation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/encapsulation-in-c/) in *OOP*.
3. Simple way to solve your task is to have an array of objects.

   ```
   Player playes[] = {
      {60, 40, 60, "wizard"},
      ...
      {70, 30, 70, "warrior"},
   };
   ```

   But in such case you create redundant *objects*. If user choose
   `warrior` - you don't need other objects according to your code.
   Keeping redundant *objects* is wasting memory. More professional
   (doesn't mean the best way, since in different situations different
   approaches can be used, in practise sometimes array of objects may
   be better) would be to use some of creational *design pattern*. For
   example [Factory Pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/factory-method/cpp/example) or [Factory Method](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/factory-method-without-switch-case)

Comment: What if I would create constructors for each of them and when the other roles (I now i realize the confusion, I meant classes as in player is choosing from them) are not chosen i destruct them? Also, I have to find a way to be able to modify the numeric values because of the items and level up of the stats. I'm searching for a way to create a valarray. Or maybe I will create vectors from the values I want to increase and do vector aritmethics. At least I hope it will work:)

Comment: encapsulation not incapsulation :-)

Comment: Thank you @UpAndAdam,

Comment: @Enthale 
In general, create all objects, and deconstruct part of them without using tehm  looks like a crutch - you waste CPU for creating an object, you waste RAM for some period of time, you waste CPU for destoying.. It would be better to create an object only when you really need it. But it depends on a situation, for example if object construction is time consuming, and you must process user's answers super-fast, - keeping all objects in memory may looks like a reasonable tradeoff.
A way to  modify the numeric values : void AddAttack(int val) { attack+=val; }

Answer (score 0):

One key catch here on your wording above thats important in improving your understanding.  You aren't selecting which class to call it on. You only have one class `Player` you are choosing which `instance` of `Player` to call it on.  This would be slightly more challenging if you actually made different classes for the different 'character classes'... you'll see why as I elaborate below.

A similar idea is to use a pointer, `Player *chosen`; use the switch to select a player and assign it to `chosen` so that you have `chosen = &wizard` for example... now no matter what you have picked you can do `chosen->getAttack()` or even more powerful make the enemy a `Player` object and create a fight or attack method that takes a second `Player` by reference or pointer.... i.e. `chosen->fight(monster)`. where internally all the various fields are modified as a result of them fighting.. 
If you need specialization you should subclass player for the different types, this is called polymorphism, and you would create virtual methods that each concrete subtype of `Player` would have to implement.   This allows you to treat them all as 'Players' regardless of whether its a say `Wizard` or a `DrunkenOaf`, you could created classes for the different types of characters and the internals of each class does what is needed which may vary class by class ( otherwise you wouldn't need the different classes )  An example might be printing an action message summary, where say assassins "stab" while wizard "casts a spell", warrior "slashes", etc.  this could also be important if you wanted different behavior for how damage was dealt 'per turn' or for how defense applied to the damage... perhaps a spell doesn't care about armor or regular defense but a physical attack does. or perhaps the spell strength is a function of both attack level AND remaining hp and mp or something like that. Perhaps there is an element of chance to whether the `drunkenoaf` misses entirely or passes out... just using that as a comical example. There are many possibilities!

there are a number of other patterns you could apply as well, such as the factory pattern, where you have a factory method and based on what you pass it it returns you the appropriate type of 'player'. This would allow you to build a party at runtime instead of hard coding the party at compile time. I would suggest keeping your party in a container as well.

Not ironically I use a text based RPG game as an example for teaching polymorphism during a lot of the c++ classes I have taught in the summer or through volunteer efforts for inner city students. It affords a lot of opportunities to highlight a number of good design patterns where object orientation really makes sense, the 'is-a' case for inheritance is actually true, and it just makes a whole lot of sense.

In any event I wouldn't abandon the OOP paradigm this is a great vehicle for learning it properly!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried a vector and einpoklum solution and both worked wonderful, yet now I'm in the need to upgrade the value, something like players[choice].getAttack() += 10, but as you would know, it doesn't work. Now I'm learning about valarray. Looks that it has dynamic data structure.

Comment: I would look at a setter instead. create a method called setAttack for the player if you need to manipulate it. A vector is already a dynamic data structure... but altering the value of your value isn't a dynamic thing. you just have to provide a mutator

Comment: if a post is useful to you it is also encouraged to upvote it :-)

Comment: I do appreciate all of them. Honestly it's hard to believe how much a few comments increased my knowledge about using/combining fuctionalities, but "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: cout << "You have gained 5 attack!\n\n";
                        gold = gold - 300;
                        players[choice].setAttack += 5;
                        break;                   I tried to do as you suggested, but with no avail. I have to look into it tomorrow as     void setAttack(int atk)
    {
        attack = atk;
    }   its not enough yet

Comment: you cant get call `setAttack += 5`, setAttack is a setter and take an integer argument, if you find you are very often incrementing or decrementing current value you should use  `void modifyAttack(int x) { attack += x; attack = std::max(attack, 0);} // if you don't allow negative attack values` other wise you could use `players[choice].setAttack(players[choice].getAttack() + 5 );` which is partially why I suggested even if you keep them in an array structure getting a pointer or reference to your player object